# When can we call a loss function "adaptive"?

Tags: machine-learning, objective-functions, generative-adversarial-networks

A loss function is a measure of how bad our neural network is. We can decrease the loss by proper training.

I came across the phrase "adaptive loss function" in several research papers. For example: consider the following excerpt from the "Introduction" of the research paper titled [Generative Adversarial Text to Image Synthesis](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/reed16.pdf) by Scott Reed et al.

> By conditioning both generator and discriminator on side information, we can naturally model this phenomenon since the discriminator network acts as a "smart" **adaptive** loss function.

When can we denote a loss function as adaptive? Is it a mathematical property or is solely based on the context?

Comment: It is the normal English meaning of "adaptive".

Comment: @user253751 So, if the loss function is changing according to the need, then can I say it as adaptive?

Comment: Sure. It is the normal English meaning. It is not something with a precise mathematical definition, as far as I'm aware. AI papers are not a programming language.

Comment: Did you come across the term in context other than GANs? I can see how the discriminator might be considered to present an "adaptive" loss function for GANs as user253751 states. More specifically, the loss value for the generator will change - the same generated image will receive different loss values as the discriminator improves.

Comment: @NeilSlater I think I came across in GANs only.